# When does the $L_1$ convergence imply almost everywhere convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

I know that $L_1$ convergence implies existence of an almost everywhere converging subsequence.
But I was wondering, can you tell me some extra conditions on functions that make $L_1$ convergence imply a.e. convergence?

Comment: One condition that is sometimes useful is monotonicity, though this is very strong.  Did you have an application in mind?

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by felipeh, if $0\leqslant X_{n+ 1}(\omega)\leqslant    X_n(\omega)$ for each $n$ and each $\omega$, and $\mathbb E[X_n]\to 0$, then $X_n\to 0$ a.s. (the almost convergence for the subsequence actually holds for the whole sequence).

An other case of interest is when the series $\sum_n\mathbb E|X_n-X|$ is convergent. In this case, an application of the Borel-Cantelli lemma shows that $X_n\to X$ almost surely.