# $L_1$ convergence implies a.s. convergence for a sequence that is monotonically decreasing in $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Basically my question is how to prove (if true) that $L_1$ convergence implies a.s. convergence for a sequence that is monotonically decreasing in $n$. (not just for a subsequence)

More formally, for a sequence of measurable functions $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$,

> If $0\leq X_{n+1}(\omega) \leq X_{n}(\omega)$ for each $n$ and each $\omega$, and $\mathbb{E}[X_n]\to0$ then $X_n \to 0$ almost surely.

It was inspired by this post [When does the $L_1$ convergence imply almost everywhere convergence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1202715/when-does-the-l-1-convergence-imply-almost-everywhere-convergence?rq=1) but I have not been able to find a reference or proof for it.

Comment: By basic real analysis, a decreasing sequence of functions always has a pointwise a.e. limit. The subsequence argument you are referring to shows that $L^1$ limits and pointwise a.e. limits agree almost everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose for a contradiction that $X_n$ does not converge to $0$ almost surely. Then there exists a set $E$ of positive measure and $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for each $\omega \in E$ there exists a sequence $n_k(\omega)$ such that $X_{n_k(\omega)}(\omega) > \varepsilon$ for all $k \geq 1$.

By Monotonicity, we obtain that $X_n(\omega) > \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq 1$.

This implies that $\mathbb{E}[X_n] \geq \mathbb{P}(E) \varepsilon > 0$ which is in contradiction with $L^1$ convergence to $0$.

Comment: I don't quite follow "By Monotonicity, we obtain that Xn(ω)>ε for all n≥1." Isn't it only true to n≥nk(ω)?

Comment: @ChadBrown $n \mapsto X_n(\omega)$ is decreasing in $n$. So if $n < n_k(\omega)$ then $X_n(\omega) \geq X_{n_k(\omega)}(\omega) > \varepsilon$. Since $n_k(\omega)$ can be taken arbitrarily large we can conclude.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X(\omega)=\inf_nX_n(\omega)=\lim_nX_n(\omega)$.  Then by the Monotone Convergence Theorem, one has that $X_n\to X$ in $L^1$.

By assumption $X_n\to0$ in $L^1$ as well, so the uniqueness of the limit implies that $X=0$ a.s.